# Sinatra: three logs

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm using a very simple Sinatra app that works well. However, every log message is repeated three times. I can bring that down to two by disabling the Sinatra logging with

```
disable :logging
```

but I still have two. The messages are slightly different, so I gather they are coming from Rack and somewhere else in the stack too.

How do I completely disable logging of successful web requests?

Comment: Where are you enabling the logging?

Comment: @Tom: I'm not enabling it anywhere. I'm just using default settings.

Comment: Any `require 'logger'` or such in `config.ru`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rack is adding own logging as a middleware
try to run

```
rackup -E none
```

This removes one log entry. The second one is sinatra native which you've already disable. And the third one is Rack::Lint logging if I remember correctly.
General approach is to restructure your app like

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "hello"
  end
end
```

config.ru

```
require 'myapp'
run MyApp
```

Or you can run app outside rack

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  App.run!
end
```