# How to customize Sinatra logging level

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I redirected Sinatra output to log file. I was wondering how to skip all requests and write only errors Eg.

```
localhost - - [22/Dec/2010:15:47:32 AUSEDT] "GET /db/OMSGDV03/tlm HTTP/1.1" 200 93
    - -> /A/B/C
```

shouldn't appear

Comment: Found answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282765/sinatra-three-logs. Please feel free to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off requests logging with:

```
set :logging, false
```